# Sending Parameters to Rest Api with httpost in java as an array

Tags: java, rest

I am connecting to a rest api when I do the post without parameters I get a return but as soon as I try to add parameters

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("ID", "44");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
    post.setEntity(se);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

to filter the data i get the following reply

> {"error":"ERROR_CORE","error_description":"TASKS_ERROR_EXCEPTION_#256;
>   Param #0 (arOrder) for method ctaskitem::getlist() expected to be of
>   type \u0022array\u0022, but given something else.;
>   256/TE/WRONG_ARGUMENTS\u003Cbr\u003E"}

How do I send the parameters as an array?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
List<String> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add("44");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("arOrder", orders);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
post.setEntity(se);
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

After reading the docs, please try to send the following JSON:

```
[
  { "ID" : "desc" }, 
  { "ID" : ["44"] }, // or [44] plain int
  [ "ID", "TITLE"]
]
```

Comment: Not getting the error now but the data is not filtered this is the info i have about the api http://www.bitrixsoft.com/rest_help/tasks/task/items/getlist.php

Comment: What is the package for `JSONObject`?

Comment: What you need to send is: `[ { "ID" : [ "44" ] } ]`. Can you construct such query yourself?

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: I can try do not know if i will succeed.

Comment: Do i need a JSONArray?

Comment: Yes, you need it, twice.

Comment: so this should work ??   JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
       list.add("44");
       
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
       obj.put("ID",list);
       
       JSONArray lis2 = new JSONArray();
       lis2.add(obj);   
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(lis2.toJSONString());
    post.setEntity(se);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

Comment: Still gives all the data

Comment: Ok. Since I can't set it up - time limitations - this is the whole help I can offer. See my answer edit for the last attempt.

Comment: if i print the StringEntity se it gives [Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 15,Chunked: false] is that correct

Comment: No, it's not. Content type should be set to `application/json`.

Comment: No still returnes all the data